# Remove the text until the matching string using regex

Tags: regex, workflow

I am having an issue with using regex for deleting everything before the String.

Given String: `xyz@gmail.com No TEST NOTE. If you are not an intended recipient`

Expected result: `TEST NOTE. If you are not an intended recipient`

The regex I am using to delete the  preceding part is `[^*] * No`

But it is deleting a part of the expected result as well and giving me `t an intended recipient` as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match exactly the part, that you want to delete:

```
^[^\s]+\sNo\s
```

Comment: This is dangerous in case there's more text in the string that could include the word ` No `.

Comment: @dx_over_dt At the moment, the question does not give any hints, that the word "No" may vary. We only know that "TEST NOTE. If you are not an intended recipient" will not be constant as he would then just match against that.

Comment: @Thomas I think I just tried yours and it is working. thanks a lot. I appreciate everyone in this conversation

Comment: Also the regex I am trying to use is in Nintex workflow to delete the text that I get and update the Notes Column

Comment: @Thomas the solution you gave is not working in the below scenario
xyz@gmail.com No Not available in the store. Ask the seller. Item is NORM.
I want everything deleted until/including "No"
desired output:  Not available in the store. Ask the seller. Item is NORM.

Comment: @Ashok What makes you think it does not work? It works for both your examples. Check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/fzi3Fn/1). You should probably tell us, how you are deleting the part that you match. May be you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `*` which is greedy.  Try using `*?` which is lazy.

I'm not actually sure how your regex is deleting everything up to `t an intended recipient`.  You probably want your regex to be

```
/^.*? No /i
```

The `^` may not be what you want if the email address isn't necessarily at the start of the string.

Also, if you want to delete everything up to `TEST NOTE` rather than everything up through and including `No`, you might try

```
/^.*?(?=TEST NOTE)/i
```

Comment: Still the same, I have tried [^*?]*No and [^*]*?No of no luck.

Comment: Sec, I'll mess around with it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it

Comment: @dx the regex I am trying to use is in Nintex workflow and Thomas answer has served the purpose and I appreciate all the help and answers you gave, thanks

Comment: Its now not working in this case,
xyz@gmail.com No Item is NORM. cannot transfer NORM items. Please get with seller.

Comment: You want to cut everything up to "Item"?  My first regex should work for that

Comment: No It is not working dx please see the below
scenario: xyz@gmail.com No Not available in the store. Ask the seller. Item is NORM.
I want everything deleted until/including "No" 
desired output: Not available in the store. Ask the seller. Item is NORM

Comment: @Ashok It's working for me. https://regex101.com/r/srcDUc/1 Is it not matching anything or is it matching too much?

Comment: It is not matching anything. it just doesn't do anything

Comment: Copy and paste your scenario into that link, and see if it matches the front of the string

Answer (score 0):

`^` to begin from the start of the `str`. `(.*?)` will match everything until `No` and not further. Second group `(.*)` will match everything after `No`. `"$2"` returns the second group.

```js
const str = "xyz@gmail.com No TEST NOTE. If you are not an intended recipient"
const res = str.replace(/^(.*?)No (.*)/, "$2")
console.log(res)

const str2 = "xyz@gmail.com No Not available in the store. Ask the seller. Item is NORM"
const res2 = str2.replace(/^(.*?)No (.*)/, "$2")
console.log(res2)
```

Your regex works the way it works because

1. `[^*]` means everything but `*`... and you have no `*` in your string.
2. you are using **greedy** `*`, so it take everything it can until the **last** occurrence of `no` in the string.
3. and you're obviously using `i` flag, so `No` in your regex matches `No`, `NO` and `no`.

Comment: I am trying to use this regex in Nintex workflow by passing some text and please see the below, can you help me with the regex expression accurately
scenario: xyz@gmail.com No Not available in the store. Ask the seller. Item is NORM. I want everything deleted until/including "No"
desired output: Not available in the store. Ask the seller. Item is NORM

Comment: The same regex works just fine. Updated the answer with new provided string. Any way, you should update your question with an abstract description of **all strings** you want to match against. Because right now you question is similar to asking "what is the next number in the sequence [1,2,3,4,...]" and it can be **any number** if we do not know the rule this sequence is based on.